# How to clean a string by removing anything that is not a letter in PHP

Tags: php, html

lets say I have an html document

how can I remove every thing from the document

I want to remove the HTML tags

I want to remove any special character

I want to remove everything except letters

and extract the text

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/strip_tags) and [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) to accomplish this:

```
function clean($in)
{
    // Remove HTML
    $out = strip_tags($in);
    // Filter all other characters
    return preg_replace("/[^a-z]+/i", "", $out);
}
```

`[^a-z]` will match any character other than A to Z, the `+` sign specifies that it should match any sequence length of such characters and the `/i`-modifier specifies that it's a case insensitive search. All matched characters will be replaced with an empty string leaving only the characters left.

If you want to keep spaces you can use `[^a-z ]` instead and if you want to keep numbers as well `[^a-z0-9 ]`. This allows you to whitelist all allowed characters and discard the rest.

Comment: While that answers the question in the title, it doesn't remove html tags, which the body suggests he wants removed...

Comment: True. See Jeremys answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use [strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip_tags) to get rid of HTML first, then use Emil H's regex.

Answer (score 2):

Prepend a

```
$in = preg_replace("/<[^>]*>/", "", $in);
```

to Emil H's solution, so your Tags will get striped. Else, a "<p>Hello World</p>" will appear as "pHelloWorldp"